# Different view of component on every ngFor iteration

Tags: angular6, ngfor

I have an array of object and I am running `ngFor` on that, I want to show different view for each iteration of `ngFor`

```
const HEROES = [
    {id: 1, name:'Superman'},
    {id: 2, name:'Batman'},
    {id: 5, name:'BatGirl'},
    {id: 3, name:'Robin'},
    {id: 4, name:'Flash'}
];
```

Like Superman should be default view than when I click next batman should be shown the next will be batgirl and so on.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share what you have tried so far, and where exactly you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the index without using the ngFor by following these steps.

1. Create Default View Component to show the Name
2. Create Component to show next name and use ngIf to hide/show that component.
3. Use a variable and iterate with that.

I have created a small prototype which can explain the steps mentioned above.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-for-loop